# I want to know how can I build platforms to do SPARQLqueries on RDF, especially what programming tools do I need

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, jena

I am doing research on fuzzy SPARQL queries. I present an extended syntax, f-SPARQL. I would like to complete a system to validate this syntax by doing queries on RDF. As I know little about the RDF query implements, I want to know how can I build platforms to do SPARQL queries and what programming tools do I need. for example, Jena TDB eclipse or something else.

Comment: May I suggest that you also have a look on answers.semanticweb.com, which is a Stackoverflow-like site specifically about Semantic Web tech. You may find some useful listings of tools and tutorials there.

Answer (score 2):

[Apache Jena's ARQ](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/arq-query-eval.html) has a large number of [extension points](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/extension.html) for adding, among other things, Filter Functions and Property Functions. Several projects ([LARQ](http://jena.sourceforge.net/ARQ/lucene-arq.html) and [SpatialIndex](https://code.google.com/p/geospatialweb/wiki/SpatialIndex), for example) have utilized these extension points to add functionality. I recommend reviewing the links on ARQ, and the code-bases for these projects, as they will provide you with some guidance and some examples.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you can provide a [SAIL API](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/system/ch05.html) implementation of your language extension.

Answer (score 1):

To import dataset into Jena TDB, you can just run it at command prompt and query it inside your project.

load it in windows command prompt by the following:

```
java -jar c:\your_ontology_directory\fuseki-server.jar  --file=your_ontology.rdf /your_datasetname
```

then you can SPARQL query it with any GET/POST application (even in your browser):

```
http://localhost:3030/your_namespace/sparql?query=SELECT * { ?s ?p ?o }
```

The results are returned in XML format.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sparql xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/sparql-results#">
  <head>
    <variable name="s"/>
    <variable name="p"/>
    <variable name="o"/>
  </head>
  <results>
    <result>
      <binding name="s">
        <uri>http://yago-knowledge/resource/wordnet_gulag_103467887</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="p">
        <uri>http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#subClassOf</uri>
      </binding>
      <binding name="o">
        <uri>http://yago-knowledge/resource/wordnet_prison_camp_104005912</uri>
      </binding>
    </result>
    ...
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Good Luck with your adventure ;)

You can learn Sparql using O'Reilly Media, Inc. **Learning SPARQL**.

This book is a great resource for Sparql. 
Also, you can use **Twinkle** Sparql for checking your Sparql queries locally, as well as to your dbPedia.
[Twinkle Sparql](http://www.ldodds.com/projects/twinkle/)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll explain my confusion further. I want to do such a system:accept user's fuzzy query(based on my f-sparql syntax) and the system will translate the fuzzy query into crisp SPARQL query according to my translation rules, then the system will executes the query and returns the results from RDF dataset. I want to get some information on how do I realize a system:including prgramming tools and how to import dataset into Jena TDB(if it is needed).

Comment: If you are starting something new, I would suggest you to use **Fuseki sparql** as engine. Also, Arc2 is API you can use.